# Is "now" UTC time in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, timestamp

The `now` keyword in Solidity returns a `uint256` with the current block timestamp.

Is the timestamp in UTC time? (ie. the number of seconds since 1st January 1970)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The miners use the UTC time as the block timestamp.